# Run as administrator checkbox in Win + R dialog

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, task-manager

Is possible to bring Run as administrator into <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> dialog? When I raise the same dialog from task manager there this checkbox is.

Expected:

[image: Expected dialog]

Current:

[image: Current dialog]

The dialog after <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (handled by explorer.exe) and in task manager (handled by taskmgr.exe) show similar, but there are different message, different window title, different icon, different window size and the most important: Checkbox for starting task as administrator. Is there any option to bring task managers dialog instead of <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> dialog.

Comment: have you tried my freeware tool? Does it work the way you want it?

Comment: I tried it by it's not more productive without auto focus field after start. When I started it, it takes more than 0.5 sec to unforze from blank window and finaly I am not friendly with third party tools to solve this.

Comment: submit your feedback to the developer of the program

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Press Windows + R to get the run dialog.
Type in your command.
Press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER instead of ENTER.

Comment: It works since Windows 10

Comment: It works since Windows 8 and also worked since Windows 7 with certain developer add-ons. I answered the question clearly and succinctly. I am not sure what your comment is attempting to clarify on an already succinct answer of "How do I?" question. Perhaps this is a language difference.

Answer (score 3):

- Press <kbd>Win</kbd> Key
- Type the command like `cmd`
- Press → <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: searching in Start is so slow on my HDD notebook. That is not solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

this is not possible, but there s a 3rd party tool called [Run-Command](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Microsoft/Run-Command)

> Run-Command is a small, portable windows program and created as an
>   alternative to the standard Windows Run-Dialog.
>
> In this program you will find a number of improvements e.g. **the
>   function run as administrator** and add to favorites commands for
>   frequently used commands.

[image]

Comment: "this is not possible" is an incorrect statement.